# Get region areas using Convexhull function Matlab

Tags: matlab, scatter-plot, area, convex-hull

so I am trying to calculate some areas on a matlab plot. Using the scatter function I get a plot like this:
[image]

The color corresponds to a fibre orientation in degrees
Now I an trying to get the area for each region of 10 degrees. For instance, I'm taking all the dots from 10 to 20 degree. Let's say I have 3 distinct regions.  I want to use the convexhull to be able to extrapolate and get the area. 
To be more clear, using the following loop:

```
c=z1>10 & z1 < 20;
c=c.*1;
for i=1:length(z1)
    if z1(i)< 20 && z1(i)> 10
        c(i) = 1;
    else
        c(i)=0;
    end

end
```

I locate the dots in that region and replot the scatter:
[image]

Now all the red dots corresponds to angles between 10 and 20, the rest is blue. I want to be able to label each region and circle them to get the area using convexhull. I think I have to turn the thing in black and white, then enlarge each dot to circle so they touch each other, the fill any hole so you have  uniform region and then apply the convexhull function. But I have no idea how to do all that. If anyone has any suggestion?
Thanks very much

EDIT: so instead of doing `scatter(x1,y1,3,c,'filled')` 
I create a matrix `B=[c c c]` to get a color matrix, and then inverse the 0 and 1 by doing this `B = ~B;` then I get a picture like this with `scatter(x1,y1,3,B,'filled')`  which I think I can use directly for convexhull?

[image]